# Why is cmd show error while downloading linux using " vagrant up" command?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I already install virtualbox, vagrant in my windows machine(8.1, 64 bit).
Using cmd at the vagrant folder, i use vagrant up command like bellow.

```
vagrant/vagrant up
```

It start download,but after sometime, it showing the error:
OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 10054

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`errno 10054` is `WSAECONNRESET` -- the connection dropped. Start looking at your network connectivity.